# Weird error when reversing the contents of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reverse

I'm trying to reverse the contents of this array, but the result is subtracting 2 from the values in the array for some reason.

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Code:

```
function reverseArray(array) {
  var newArray = [];
  for (i = array.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    newArray.push(array.indexOf(i));
  };
  return newArray;
};

var testArray = ["Zach", 2, 3, 4, 5];
var result = reverseArray(testArray);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Comment: Debug your code. Place a breakpoint on the `newArray.push` line. There, examine `array.indexOf(i)` and see if it is what you want. Fix your code, rinse, and repeat. Or, just use `Array#reverse`.

Comment: @torazaburo: LOL! I literally was writing that in my answer when you commented. :-)

Comment: Appreciate the feedback. The point of the exercise I'm doing is to not use the reverse method. Thanks though.

Answer (score 2):

`newArray.push(array.indexOf(i));` pushes the **index** of the value in `i` in the array (if it's there), or `-1` if not. E.g., it's looking for the values `4`, `3`, `2`, `1` and `0` and, if it finds them, pushing the index at which it found them into the new array.

To understand this better, change your function slightly and then step through it in the debugger:

```
function reverseArray(array) {
  var newArray = [];
  for (i = array.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var newValue = array.indexOf(i);
    newArray.push(newValue);       // <=== Put a breakpoint on this line
  };
  return newArray;
}
```

Then step through that with the debugger and, on the indicated line, look at the value of `newValue` each time through the loop. (There's a powerful debugger built into your browser.)

You just want `newArray.push(array[i]);`

---

Side note: You also want to declare your `i` variable; currently, you're falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html).

Side note 2: You don't put a `;` after a function declaration, or after the block attached to a `for` loop.

Comment: So what happened to meta-mode approach to teaching people how to fish?

Comment: @torazaburo: I explained what was going on, then thought, I'll go back and tell them how they'd figure that out themselves. You may not have seen the second bit. It was truly amazing timing, I hit Save Edits and your comment appeared on the question. :-)